# Android 11 Permission Issue

Tags: android, flutter, android-11

my flutter code is

```
 var storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
    var root = storageInfo[0]
        .rootDir; 
    var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); 
     await fm.filesTree(
        excludedPaths: [
          '/storage/emulated/0/Android',
        ],
        extensions: ['pdf']
        );
```

error occur

```
E/flutter (16591): FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
E/flutter (16591): #0      FileManager.dirsTree (package:flutter_file_manager/src/file_manager.dart:110:7)
E/flutter (16591): #1      FileManager.filesTree (package:flutter_file_manager/src/file_manager.dart:132:34)
```

I have one issue to get list of files from stroage in android 11 from Flutter app

i already add both permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: On an Android 11 device you have no access to the../Android/obb directory. Not even with all files access.

Comment: i went to read only specific extension file from storage

Comment: No you wanna list the obb directory i see.

Comment: then how can i retrieve document file list from storage

Comment: Please be exact. It cannot from obb directory you know now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to request manage_external_storage permission via permission_handler.

Add this permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Request permission as shown below

```
await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
```

Then we can read any file and write to any location in Android 11.

Comment: we can use this but Google Play console will not allow the app with this permission to release.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution will be to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `AndroidManifest` file and in `build.gradle` change `targetSdkVersion 29` whereas keeping `compileSdkVersion 30`. This should work fine.